# KStream with multiple nodes

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, apache-kafka-streams

Building stream application using kafka stream. I have topic with 8 partition, where application keep posting/publishing the message to topic and created a Kstream on top of this topic. so far good with creating stream as i started only one instance(JVM), as per the documentation, stream create in local JVM, but my problem is if if move code into QA or production,  I will have 8 JVM runs parallel, hence 8 streams getting created per JVM...

Now, my real time service(micro service) code tries to read the data from stream(ip address are behind netscaler), how will it behave because of stream is in location .. all my 8 instance will be having same copy of the data or else wil be partial ?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:   It will be "partial".**

In a Kafka Streams application with a basic topology with one input topic only, assuming one thread per application instance (`num.stream.threads`), if you launch several application instances with the same application name, they will share the partitions that you have in your input topic.

For example, if you have 8 partitions and you launch 8 KafkaStreams instances like this, each will manage one partition (this distribution happens automatically).
It will also be fault tolerant: if any of the 8 applications die - then the extra partition will be managed by one of the other 7 remaining tasks. Also, if you add one extra task (to have 9 over 8 partitions), one of them will remain idle, and will pick up only in case of failure of any of the other instances.